# Proportional stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to make a stacked bar graph in which one variable is the proportion of a second variable. The data is

```
   snps2       ors2       orm2
1  ABCA7     0.00000000  0.4140283  
2  B1NI      0.00000000  0.3140075  
3  CD2AP     0.00000000  0.2087200
4  CD33      0.22665737  0.2266574  
5  CLU       0.12221763  0.2444353  
6  CR1       0.00000000  0.3140075  
7  EPAH1     0.22665737  0.2266574  
8  MS4A4A    0.24443527  0.2444353  
9  MS4A4E    0.07696104  0.1539221  
10 MSA6A     0.20872003  0.2087200  
11 PICALM    0.12221763  0.2444353  
12 APOE_e2   0.00000000 -1.3862944  
13 APOE_e4   0.00000000  2.6752584
```

The values for ors2 will always be either 0%, 50% or 100% of the value of orm2.
I have restructured this into a long format for use in ggplot2.

```
dat_m <- melt(mydata)
ggplot(dat_m, aes(snps2, value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

This gives me the following graph:

[image]

However, the red values rather then been a proportion of the green values which is what I want, they have been added onto each other.

How can I get it so that ors2 is a proportion of orsm2 in graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in a stacked barplot, values are always summed up, you just have to substract before plotting: orm2 = orm2 - ors2

[image]

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)


mydata$orm2_adj=mydata$orm2-mydata$ors2
summary(mydata)
dat_m <- melt(mydata[,-3])

ggplot(dat_m, aes(snps2, value, fill = variable,color=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","transparent"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a dodged barplot instead of a stacked one:

```
ggplot(dat_m, aes(snps2, value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position='dodge')
```

[image]

In a stacked barplot, values are always summed up.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise change your variable like

```
dat$orm2 <- dat$orm2 - dat$ors2
```

then do

```
dat_m <- melt(mydata)
ggplot(dat_m, aes(snps2, value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```